# How to secure WCF web services hosted from a Windows Service?

Tags: wcf, web-services, wcf-security, wcf-client

I have a one question about WCF web service security.Currently, we are developing one android mobile project and using wcf web service for data transfer and manipulation.
We use basicHttpBinding and hosted the web service as **Window Service**.

We don't have any security mode at the moment and I am afraid of every one can consume our web service if they know the service address.
For example, we have one service method and that will return string value.  Currently, I can add that service to other visual studio project and mobile project and we can consume any time.

```
//WCF Service Method
public string DoWork()
{
      return "This is return string!";
}

    //We can consume it like below from other dot net project by adding service reference.
   //Actually, those are not real client.
    ServiceReference1.WebServiceClient serv = new TestingPrj.ServiceReference1.WebServiceClient();
    string result = serv.DoWork();
```

My question is how can I secure my web service  for real clients? I don't want other projects and people to consume our web services.

Comment: There's lots of help here: https://www.google.com/#q=securing+wcf+web+services

Comment: I already try but most of the answers are for webservices hosted in IIS.  Thats why I put the question here.  Anyway, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest method is to use Basic Authentication over SSL.  Basic Authentication requires the client to have a username/password pair, which only your application will know.  If the authentication is purely to know if your client is the right one (rather than knowing which user is connecting), then you can use a single, hard-coded username/password.

SSL should be used as well so the credentials don't travel the wire in plain-text and can potentially be sniffed.

Answer (score 0):

Using ssl certificates is the most secure way.

Comment: How do ssl certificates protect against the wrong user accessing the service?

Comment: We host the services as window service and we don't use IIS server.
Is it possible to use SSL cerficicates in this way?

Comment: Yes, you can do it either through configuration file or coding the service to require HTTPS.  If you have the certificate installed on the server where the windows service is running, it should bind to the certificate.

Comment: thanks mellamokb.Could you able to share me some links or examples? I am newbies in web services and security.